# Error called "init() unavailable" while using Firebase to authenticate users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
let uid = FirebaseAuth.Auth().currentUser?.uid;
```

whenever I try to retrieve the user's uid, I get the error that the init() is unavailable. I am using firebase in order to authenticate users and not not a user to register if the email they are registering with is already in use.
help please!!

Comment: Try:  let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

Comment: According to the documentation for the latest version of the SDK,  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users, it should be
`let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`

Comment: let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid works well in my current project using FirebaseAuth (3.1.1) pod and swift 3

Comment: Thanks @JenPerson , It worked for me.